# Using Highcharts to make correct graphs on RoR apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, redmine

I am using the Highcharts library to create charts on ROR application (plugin in Redmine). I used [this video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts?view=comments) as an example.

My problem is that every chart I want to draw will be formed as a "Line chart".

For example:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1,        95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

As you can notice, I put:

```
chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
```

But it will be a line chart, not a column chart.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? have you checked highchart API? I don't think that this is Rails related up to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the type like this:

```
chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
```

or you can set different types for series like this:

```
{
            name: 'London',
            type: 'line',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            type: 'column',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FWHGx/6/

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly odd. It not caching maybe? Try clearing and reloading the page.

Comment: My problem is whatever the kind of chart that I want to draw to get, its type will be always    (type: 'line') .

Comment: Even on this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) if you change the type it works. I have used highcharts extensively before and never encountered a problem like this.